# When using Mod_rewrite does google bot see the original url or the rewritten url?

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, googlebot

If i use the bellow code in my .htacess file would google bot (or any other search spiders) see the example.tumblr.com url or would they see the same url as the user ie. example.co.uk/blog ?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.co.uk/blog$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/standard
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.tumblr.com$1   [R]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google sees the same URL your users see. They don't have access to your htaccess file just like everybody else.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of any redirect, Google (and your users' browsers) will be presented with *both* URL's.

In the case you presented, however, the users' browsers will *display* the first URL while the contents of the second URL are requested as you are issuing a 302 Temporary redirect (which implies that the URL the user requested is only being redirected temporarily).

Users are not able to determine the actual URL if you are using mod_rewrite to translate URL's being passed to Apache or as a proxy, however, the example provided is not such a case.

Comment: Does google see this as borderline blackhat, or is it ok ? How could i change it to pass it to apache as you mensioned ?

Comment: There is nothing "blackhat" about this method, however, Google recommends that you use a [canonical URL](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) in this situation. Rather than proxying requests, you should use Tumblr's [custom domain](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_domains) feature to implement a subdomain for your Tumblr blog.

Comment: i agree the simplest way to do this would be to have tumblr on the subdomain but we want it on the subdirectory so that we get the benefit of the backlinks back to the root domain